# What are the advantages of hosting your API(s) and IdentityServer4 host separately (C#, .NET CORE)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Perhaps the question I am about to ask is very obvious and simple, but as a beginner in IdentityServer4 and more or less in oAuth2, OpenID and API's in general, I find it quite hard to understand.

Our company's goal is to move to a more secure application building way (Visual Studio 2017, C#, .NET Core 2) using Authentication and Authorization. After some days of research I ended up with using IdentityServer4 (also because the documentation is really great).

After following the IdentityServer Documentation (https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/identityserver4/release/identityserver4.pdf) up till chapter 7, I have one remaining.

I am trying to build a MVC application (web) with an API backend for retrieving / inserting the data so that I can later use the API for other applications, like a SPA / Xamarin application. For the IdentityServer host I went for IdentityServer with asp.net identity. I got it running and it all works great, however the following question remains:

What are the disadvantages of hosting my API, in which I want to handle Database operations, together with the IdentityServer host? 
It doesn't seem logical to me to have so many different projects while (so far as I can tell) these 2 (the API and IdentityServer host) can be joined together perfectly fine.

In (almost) all the examples found of IdentityServer4 the IdentityServer host and API's are separate projects, what are the advantages of hosting the two as separate projects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say Single Responsibility.

Treat it like this - Identity Server is a framework, that provides you the authentication against your clients/API's. That's it! (of course this is all done based on your rules, policies etc).

It is not Identity Servers' purpose to add/edit/delete users from your database. It is not Identity Servers' purpose to give roles to this users.
And most important - it is not Identity Servers' purpose to authorize this users.

All these must be done in your clients/api's.

In your case - you need a separate API that will take care for the users (and other data that you need), but I guess that you want this API to be protected by Identity Server.

This is where the separation comes and should be kept - Identity Server should not authenticate its own API against himself.

There is a reason that all the examples, articles and etc are with separated projects.

PS: Of course there are some examples of achieving this ([damienbod's one](https://damienbod.com/2016/10/01/identityserver4-webapi-and-angular2-in-a-single-asp-net-core-project/) is good).

Comment: Please discuss the advantage of using a token server, and not what it doesn't do

Comment: I'm missing your point - It is obvious that he has already chosen the technologies, and is just asking what are the disadvantages of running the server and the API in the same project. And this is what I'm answering.

Comment: OP "In (almost) all the examples found of IdentityServer4 the IdentityServer host and API's are separate projects, what are the advantages of hosting the two as separate projects." -> Why should my token server be seperate from my application

Comment: Well, I've also answered this - Single responsibility. The token server's job is to issue and validate tokens. Its not his job to deal with user CRUD operations.

Comment: That's a bit terse, but this question is a bit vague so I'll give you the upvote

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 Thanks for clearing it up! The only thing i'm still confused about is then why the asp.net identity part, which (if I am not wrong) is also a part of Database information (user data like usernames and passwords) is implemented in the IndetiyServer host while the User part is done, or should be done, in the API?

Comment: Identity server is reading from the database, to validate the user info, so that it can do his job - authenticate or not

Comment: If you look up authentication versus authorization, as well as look up Dominick Baier's remarks on the subject, that will clear things up a bit.

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 You say "Identity Server should not authenticate its own API against himself.". So it isn't clear to me what do you suggest. How to authenticate the API?

Comment: I suggest that you have 2 different projects. And the API, responsible for the CRUD operations over the users, should not be part of the Identity Server project, because it's not it's responsibility. The token server only authenticates (issues a token based on some credentials) and that's it. All other operations over these users, should be done separately and not as part of the token server.

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 oh, I had misunderstood you. So we can have a separate API for user management stuff and we can authenticate to that api via identity server

Comment: @HarutyunImirzyan - Yes, this is exactly what I wanted to say.