# IdentityServer4 retrieve both cookie and token during login

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have got an [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/) project where i protect an API. **Inside the Identity Server project** i am developing a mini dashboard where i have added some basic administration features like adding clients, scopes, webhooks etc. Also, inside this dashboard, i want to display some information that comes from the API. The problem is that i need not only a cookie (to login to the Identity Server) but also a user token to communicate with the API and fetch the required data. Is this a valid scenario?

I could of course make a separate call, during the initial login, and get a token by using the user's credentials but this does not sound like the best practise, so i want to avoid it at first place.

Also this dashboard could be a completely separate project and use the [Hybrid Flow](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html) to achieve the desired functionality but i did not want to create a third project for this. Do you believe this is the optimal solution though?

Thank you in advance for your opinions and answers.

Comment: The **better** approach is to have it in a separate project. Check my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286951/what-are-the-advantages-of-hosting-your-apis-and-identityserver4-host-separate/49287162#49287162 . Of course everything around this topic is opinion based