# IdentityServer4 and user management

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I've been crushing all over the web to found some data about IdentityServer4 and what it's really used for.

For what I've understand so far, IdentityServer4 is the token issuer and it's the system that will keep the link between what ressources a specific client can access or not. So, IdentityServer will get client identification to say if, yes or no, it has the right to access this ressource, or it will get the user identification (aka mail and password) to get a token to say if user is registered or not.

If I'm not mistaking, this means that user store has to been near IdentityServer OR that IdentityServer should be aware of every modification that has been made in user store. I haven't found some valuable thing on this, concerning the last version of identity server. Moreover, it seems that IdentityServer needs AspNet Identity, which means that information will be duplicated...

Is there anything I don't understand or getting wrong ? If not, how it is doable easily (considering I'm starting from scratch and I have to migrate an old legacy user store) ?

Comment: ASP.NET Core Identity is customizable, see [Custom storage providers for ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers) for more info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a couple of options for the user management:

1. As you said - using [Asp NET Identity](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html)
2. Using [Entity Framework](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html)
3. Using a custom logic created by yourself

Options 1 & 2 have a lot of examples and a quickstart for each of them, so I won't go deep there.

Option 3 - custom implementation. We ended up with this on our side. We had lots of custom things on our side (felt irrelevant to extend/override the EF approach), we didn't need Asp NET Identity, so decided to go with custom implementation.

More or less - we have a db, that holds our users. EF for accessing db (works with PostgreSQL, SQL Server, and a lot more, so you have the freedom here) and custom services, that serve for CRUD operations and whatever else you need for your tables.

IdentityServer allows you to hook up custom implementations of almost every service/store that it is using:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryCaching()
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
            .AddClientStoreCache<ClientStore>()
            .AddResourceStoreCache<ApiResourceStore>()
```

All of these are custom implementations of their interfaces. Also you have the freedom to modify the `AccountController`, where the actual login takes place, so you can hook up your user service there, and check against your own db.

So basically the approach here depends on you, your time frame etc.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it means that IdentityServer and user management are on the same service/api/website ? I thought we could have a dedicated IdentityServer service and a dedicated user management api

Comment: the management api, and identity server can be in a completely separate projects, and just use one and the same services. You can even create separate services for ids and user management, and just connect them to the same database.

Comment: that's the way I thought, but I was not sure. Thanks for your help !

Comment: And I would even encourage you to separate the management API and IDS itself. Just as a separation of concerns/single responsibility. You can check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286951/what-are-the-advantages-of-hosting-your-apis-and-identityserver4-host-separate/49287162#49287162 where I tried to express my theory about this a bit better.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and yes, I wasn't clear maybe, but I will create separate service for IDS and UserManagement. The only thing actually that I haven't clearly defined, is where I will host AspNet Identity tables or if I will duplicate data to keep the service independent if one of them fall

Comment: Having data duplication, can lead to syncing issues, but I guess that you have already thought about this.